# SensorServiceManager simply does not work within an android IntentService

Tags: android

I have the OpenIntent SensorServiceManager based code working within an Android Activity class, however I simply receive NO EVENTS when using it from with an Android IntentService class methods.

Will this class only receive events when defined and run within an Android Activity class ??.

If no, ie it runs anywhere, could somebody please send me an IntentService based code segment so I can see how my code differs.

So incredibly frustrating :-(

Answer (score 0):

Basically, one is not able to do so.

All Sensor related operations in terms of registration and unregistration must take place within the "main loop", ie within the onCreate () calls (or similar base life-cycle calls).

The problem with IntentHandler lifecycle calls is that they basically occur in a separate (non-main) thread and as such do not tend to lay well with the Sensor API.